# Estimation confidence of the biased coin probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How many times do we need to flip a coin to estimate the probability of it landing heads accurate to 0.01 and confidence of 99%?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know how to calculate a confidence interval of a given confidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum standard deviation of a bernouilli variable is 0.5

According to LLN, $(S_n-p)/\sqrt{p(1-p)n}$ converges towards a normal law of parameter $(0,1)$

Confidence interval of a normal law with 99% confidence is $\mu +- 2.32 \sigma$

Thus,  $ \mathbb{P}((S_n-p)/\sqrt{p(1-p)n} \in [-2.32 \sigma,2.32 \sigma]=0.99)$ where $\sigma$ is the

Which yields :

$ \mathbb{P}(|S_n-p|/n<= (2.32\times0.5)/\sqrt n) >=0.99$  (because $\sqrt{p(1-p)}<0.5$)

Since you want  $|S_n-p|<=0.01$, a sufficient condition is :

$\sqrt n>=116.31$ Thus  $n>=13530$.